# I can't link my css to my html (i have tried everything)

Tags: html, css

So I know this question has been asked about a 1000 times but I can not link my CSS file to my HTML. I am new to code and just trying to practice making a website. I have them in the same folder with the CSS file in a folder, in that folder. I am on a mac. Here is my code, please help:
[HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wd21b.png)

[CSS code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeN5g.png)

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your folder?

Comment: type="text/css" not type:"text/css". And test with a font like Georgia, you aren't referencing those fonts properly either.

Comment: You have to replace the : with = after you state the type of file you want to link to.

Answer (score 1):

While checking screenshot of your code I found that you are using

> type:"text/css"

into link tag, that should be

> type="text/css"

replace **:** with **=** and than I guess it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your folder structure looks like, but chances are high that href should be `"./css/style.css"` instead of `/css/style.css`.

Also, I recommend using:

`body {
background-color: purple;
}`

or something else than just changing the font to make sure your css is working. It's easier to see a change that way.